# Would this class initiate a second mysql connection?

Tags: php, class, inheritance

After moving from MySQL to MySQLi and OO code, I've started making my first DB class. After numerous tutorials I've read, I'm left with a simple puzzle: would my code open two connections to MySQL, and, if so, how could I prevent it? I am currently using one table (azgoth_en) for general user data and another, sess, for session data (building the second class for it). My code is the following:

```
class db {
        protected $connection, $lang;

        [...]

        function __construct($db='azgoth_en',$lang='en',$host='localhost',$uz='root',$pw='') {
            $this->lang=$lang;
            $mysqli=mysqli_connect($host,$uz,$pw,$db);
            if ($mysqli) {
                $this->connection=$mysqli;
                unset($mysqli);
            }
            else die('Mysql failed ('.mysqli_errno($mysqli).'): '.mysqli_error($mysqli));
        }       
    }

    class sessions extends db {
        var $connection;

        function open() {return true;}
        function close() {return true;}

        function read($id){
        $foo=$this->connection;
        var_dump($foo);
        #echo '_read var dump: ',var_dump(parent::query("SELECT * FROM sess")),'<hr>';
        #$id=parent::connection->real_escape_string($id);
        /*$result=mysqli_query($langCon,"SELECT `data` FROM `sess` WHERE `id`='{$id}' LIMIT 1");
        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
            echo '_read result found<hr>';
            $record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            return $record['data'];
        } */
        return null;
        }
    }
    $db=new db;
    $sessions=new sessions;
```

Forgive me if this seems like common sense to most of you, but every single tutorial I've read only mentions static method/variable inheritance and nothing about what I've actually encountered here.

Answer (score 1):

It'll open a connect every time you instantiate the object, e.g.

```
$db1 = new db;
$db2 = new db;
$db3 = new db;
```

will give you 3 db objects with 3 separate connections. If you only want a SINGLE db connection, regardless of how many times the db object is instantiated, then you'll want to look into using a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Even if I call out its' child, `$foo=new sessions;` ?

Comment: If the db constructor gets called as part of instantiating a sessions object, then yes.

Comment: Righto. Thank you for the answer, I'll read up on this Singleton business then. :)